Arrayformula for an using IFS(AND)
I want the following formula to copy down the entire column of my sheet. It works for the 1st row, but does not copy down the column.
={"Priority";
   arrayformula(IFS(AND(D2="LOW", F2="LOW"), "SHOULD DO",AND(D2="LOW", F2="HIGH"), "SHOULD NOT DO", AND(D2="HIGH", F2="HIGH"), "NEED TO DO", AND(D2="HIGH", F2="LOW"),"MUST DO"))}

My test sheet is linked below.  The formula is located on the Priority Matrix tab in cell G2.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QdW0-2mE0cbtJPS1LAt6GYlH5h1CvToK4dKxDy0e5Qg/edit?usp=sharing

AND won't work in the array formula.
There are a few different approaches you can use.
VLOOKUP
You can put your conditions and value pairs in an array and use VLOOKUP. This approach has less duplication than IF/IFS as you don't need to keep restating the range.
={"Priority"; 
   INDEX(IFNA(
     VLOOKUP(
       D2:D & F2:F, 
     { "LOWLOW",   "SHOULD DO";
       "LOWHIGH",  "SHOULD NOT DO";
       "HIGHHIGH", "NEED TO DO";
       "HIGHLOW",  "MUST DO" },2,)))} 

Multiply Conditions
You can use multiplication in place of AND. This will work, but is a bit repetitious, especially if you reuse the formula and need to change the range.
={"Priority";
  INDEX(
    LET(
      d,D2:D, f,F2:F, 
      IFS(
        (d="LOW")*(f="LOW"), "SHOULD DO",
        (d="LOW")*(f="HIGH"), "SHOULD NOT DO", 
        (d="HIGH")*(f="HIGH"), "NEED TO DO", 
        (d="HIGH")*(f="LOW"),  "MUST DO",1,)))}

IFS with &
Similar to the previous example but first concatenate the conditions with the & operator.
={"Priority";
  INDEX(
    LET(
      d,D2:D & F2:F, 
      IFS(
        d="LOWLOW", "SHOULD DO",
        d="LOWHIGH", "SHOULD NOT DO", 
        d="HIGHHIGH", "NEED TO DO", 
        d="HIGHLOW",  "MUST DO",1,)))}

